# unable to connect to bybit with twisted and autobahn

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn, tls1.3

I'm trying to connect to bybit wss but it's impossible and I don't know what could be going wrong.

It seems that I get the same error with coinbase, both have TLSv1.3, the code works because I have tried it with other exchanges, in this case okx and binance, the funny thing is that both use TLSv1.2

```
from autobahn.websocket.types import ConnectionDeny
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol, connectWS
from twisted.internet import reactor, task ,ssl
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient



# Configurar la conexión a la base de datos MongoDB
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client["Bybit_ord"]
posts = db.btc_usdc

class MyWebSocketClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onConnect(self, response):
        print("Conexión iniciada: {}".format(response.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("Conexión abierta")
        # Enviar un mensaje cuando se establezca la conexión
        self.sendMessage(json.dumps({
            "op": "subscribe",
            "args": ["orderbook.50.BTCUSDC"]
        }).encode('utf8'))

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if not isBinary:
            # Imprimir el mensaje recibido
            print("Mensaje recibido: {}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))
            # Insertar el mensaje recibido en la base de datos MongoDB
            message = json.loads(payload.decode('utf8'))
            posts.insert_one(message)
       

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("Conexión cerrada")
        print(code)
        print(reason)

    def onConnectionLost(self, reason):
        print("Conexión perdida: {}".format(reason))
        # Reconectar a la conexión WebSocket
        self.factory.resetDelay()
        WebSocketClientProtocol.onConnectionLost(self, reason)

class MyWebSocketClientFactory(WebSocketClientFactory):
    protocol = MyWebSocketClientProtocol

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print("La conexión falló: {}".format(reason))
        WebSocketClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason)
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print("La conexión se perdió: {}".format(reason))
        WebSocketClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)
        connector.connect()

def send_message():
    for protocol in factory.protocols:
        protocol.sendMessage(json.dumps({
            "op": "subscribe",
            "args": ["orderbook.50.BTCUSDC"]
        }).encode('utf8'))


factory = MyWebSocketClientFactory("wss://stream.bybit.com/v5/public/spot")
factory.protocol = MyWebSocketClientProtocol


#rate_limit = 0.1  # 100 ms
# task.LoopingCall(send_message).start(rate_limit)



reactor.connectTCP("stream.bybit.com",443,factory)
reactor.run()
```

> Conexión cerrada
> 1006
> connection was closed uncleanly ("WebSocket connection upgrade failed [400]: Bad Request")
> La conexión se perdió: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionAborted'>: Connection was aborted locally using ITCPTransport.abortConnection.

I have updated all the libraries, updated openSSL to a more recent version